# Interpreting nested HTML <blockquote>s in Python?

Tags: python, html, flask, tumblr

I have a web app that reads from the Tumblr API and reformats the way that "reblog chains" are formatted.

With Tumblr, commentary for a post is stored as HTML blockquotes. As users respond to the commentary above, another level gets added to the blockquote chain, eventually resulting in many nested reblog chains.

---

Here is an example of how a "reblog chain" looks in plain HTML:

```
<p><a class="tumblr_blog" href="http://chainsaw-police.tumblr.com/post/96158438802/example-tumblr-post">chainsaw-police</a>:</p><blockquote>

    <p><a class="tumblr_blog" href="http://example-blog-domain.tumblr.com/post/96158384215/example-tumblr-post">example-blog-domain</a>:</p><blockquote>
        <p>Here is an example of a Tumblr post.</p> <p>It can have multiple &lt;p&gt; elements sometimes. It may only have one, though, at other times.</p>
    </blockquote>

    <p>This is an example of a user “reblogging” a post. As you can see, the previous comment is stored above as a &lt;blockquote&gt;.</p>
</blockquote>

<p>This is another reblog. As you can see, all of the previous comments are stored as blockquotes, with earlier ones being residing deeper in the nest of blockquotes.</p>
```

---

[And this is what it looks like when rendered.](http://puu.sh/bdQvp/57ee7c44a8.png)

---

I want to be able to reformat the reblog chain so that it looks more like this:

**example-blog-domain:**
Here is an example of a Tumblr post.

It can have multiple <p> elements sometimes. It may only have one, though, at other times.

**chainsaw-police:**
This is an example of a user “reblogging” a post. As you can see, the previous comment is stored above as a <blockquote>.

**example-blog-domain:**
This is another reblog. As you can see, all of the previous comments are stored as blockquotes, with earlier ones being residing deeper in the nest of blockquotes.

---

I know, It's an incredibly confusing structure, hence why I'm trying to write something to make it more readable.

Is there any way to interpret the HTML and split the reblogs up into individual "comments"? For example, having an array or dict that has the username and the commentary would be more than enough. However, after messing with lxml and BeautifulSoup for months, I'm at my wits' end.

If there was even a way to do it in CSS, which I highly doubt, that would be fine.

Thanks in advance, everyone!

Comment: Why not use python's built-in HTML parser? You can use that to transform HTML.

Comment: I've used BeautifulSoup and lxml already, to no avail. I don't think the tool is the issue here. I'm having trouble actually splitting up the commentary and the usernames coherently.

Comment: So you want to change the HTML structure? If so, can you post the structure before and after, with minimal amount of noise (for example you can put "..." for link since the the link content is not relevant; same goes with text just "text" so it is short and we can see structure). Also you should describe at least one thing you tried so we can see why that didn't work. If you didn't keep it try it again and add to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[reddit user /u/joyeusenoelle has answered my question over at /r/LearnPython](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/2ezvjz/interpreting_tumblr_commentary_in_python/ck4qsfr?context=2) using a tonne of convoluted regexes that end up looking more like a voodoo magic spell than a text manipulation script.

> Lots of regexes later, I think I've solved this for an
>   arbitrarily-deep comment chain.
>
> ```
> import re
>
> with open("tcomment.txt","r") as tf:
>     text = ""
>     for line in tf:
>         text += line
> tf.close()
> text = text.replace("\n","")
> text = text.replace(">",">\n")
> text = text.replace("<","\n<")
> text = re.sub("</p>\s*<p>","<br><br>", text)
> text = text.replace("<p>\n", "")
> text = text.replace("</p>\n","\n")
> text = re.sub("<[/]{0,1}blockquote>","<chunk>",text)
> text = re.sub("<a class=\"tumblr_blog\"[^>]+?>","<chunk>",text)
> text = text.replace("</a>","")
> text = re.sub("\n+","", text)
> text = re.sub("\s{2,}"," ", text)
> text = re.sub("<chunk>\s*<chunk>","<chunk>",text)
> bits = text.split("<chunk>")
> bits[0] = "Latest:"
> comments = []
> for i in range(len(bits)):
>     temp = ""
>     j = 0 - (i+1)
>     if (len(bits)-i) > i:
>         temp = "<b>" + bits[i] + "</b> " + bits[j]
>         comments.append(temp)
>
> comments.reverse()
> for comment in comments:
>     print("<p>%s</p>" % (comment))
>     print()
> ```
>
> The line `bits[0] = "Latest:"` can be changed to whatever you want the
>   most recent comment to display, and you'll probably want to change how
>   the text comes into the script.
>
> For the text you provided, this gives me:
>
> ```
> <p><b>example-blog-domain:</b>  Here is an example of a Tumblr post.<br><br>It can have multiple &lt;p&gt; elements sometimes. It may
> ```
>
> only have one, though, at other times.
>
> ```
> <p><b>chainsaw-police:</b>  This is an example of a user "reblogging" a post. As you can see, the previous comment is stored
> ```
>
> above as a <blockquote>.
>
> ```
> <p><b>Latest:</b> This is another reblog. As you can see, all of the previous comments are stored as blockquotes, with earlier ones
> ```
>
> being residing deeper in the nest of blockquotes.
>
> e: Some thoughts: this is in Python 3, but everything but the print
>   statements should work in Python 2, I think. I used `text.split()`
>   whenever possible because direct string manipulation is typically
>   faster than regular expressions are, but that may not be appropriate
>   here. And finally, it's possible that I'm making more work for myself
>   than I need to in the substitutions section, but at this point *I've*
>   looked at the code too long to figure out if it could be slimmed down.

Answer (score 0):

I guess CSS does not have a such functionality.
You need parse to a structure by lxml, ... and render it. It is easier way. You can also create a filter using regexp that does not pass wrong items of html code.

Comment: I've tried to use lxml and regexp already, and I'm out of ideas. And I figured tat with CSS I may be able to reposition the blockquotes to look more like what I wish.

Comment: I don't have anything saved, as they all failed horribly.